Can I integrate \$v_y(y) \$ in Meyer model for MOSFET?
$$
I_D = -W \cdot Q_N(y) \cdot v_y(y)
$$
Re-write equation in terms of voltage at location y, V(y):
$$
v_y(y) = -\mu_n \cdot E_y(y) = \mu_n \cdot \frac{dV}{dy}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow 
\int dy = \int \mu_n \cdot \frac{dV}{V}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow 
v_y (y) = C_1 e^{\mbox{$\Large\frac{y} {\mu_n}$}}
$$
For \$Q_n(y)\$, use charge-control relation at location y
$$
Q_N(y) = -C_{ox} [V_{GS} - V(y) - V_T]
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
Q_N(y) = -C_{ox} [V_{GS} - C_1 e^{\mbox{$\Large\frac{y} {\mu_n}$}} - V_T]
$$

Do you understand how to do dimensional analysis as a sanity check? (It can be used for so much more than that. But it can just be used to detect insanity.) If not, get with the program. It will save you much grief.

@periblepsis I know this doesn't look right. But from mathematically perspective, I think I can integrate them together together.

Not a single equation in Meyer's 1971 paper has any dimensional analysis problems. They all check out (as they should.) I'm sure the author (and many readers) have applied that mental double-check any number of times -- because it's a quick way for a reader to decide whether or not to bother reading the paper and it's a quick way for an author to catch up on possible mistakes in transcription or errors in thinking that may have slipped in. Either way, everything should pass dimensional analysis even if the only thing needed is 1 that carries units (like 1 Kelvin/degree Celsius.)

Nope, still wrong.
It is immediately obvious that the result is wrong on dimensional grounds. The argument of the exponential needs to be unitless.
The derivation you are attempting to "correct" has been found in device physics textbooks for decades, indeed, may go back to Shockley. While it is known for errors to persist it is very uncommon and one should begin by showing exactly how and where previous work has gone wrong as (we believe) there should be only one answer given a set of assumptions. For explanations I recommend going back to authoritative sources (i.e., Streetman, Pierret, etc.)
In particular. When doing integrations be aware that V (the channel potential) is a function of y (channel position).

No you can't integrate as indicated, because there is no valid math that leads to the third line.

take a look at steps I have just updated
